# How to get multiple items from <select> with PHP?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm building a theme options page for my WordPress theme and I would like to have a functionality to select multiple items from a list.

The "one option" select code I use looks like this: http://pastie.org/684800 and it works perfectly.

I'm a PHP newbie so I tried to modify the above code to achieve the result I want. Here's what I came up with: pastie.org/684804. As you can see, I basically added a some html values `multiple="yes"` hoping it will work ;)

The code displays the select item properly, but seems to only save the last selected one. Could someone please give some advice on how to achieve saving multiple chosen items?

Comment: `multiple="yes"` is not correct. Some browsers may allow it, but `multiple="multiple"` is actually the correct way.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you change the name of the select element to end with "[]", PHP will treat it as an array. All of the selected items will be elements in the array. For example:

```
<select name="myChoices[]" multiple="multiple"> ... </select>

<?php
    $selectedChoices = $_POST['myChoices']; // selectedChoices is an array
?>
```

Comment: Could you please edit the code I have here? http://pastie.org/684892 I'm a complete beginner when it comes to PHP so I'm not sure what do you mean. I have `name="<?php echo $value['id']; ?>"` at the moment, which displays an ID I give it in an array. Should I change it to `name="<?php echo $value['id']; ?>[]"`?

Comment: Yes, you've got it:
     name="<?php echo $value['id']; ?>[]"

Comment: I've done it, but it doesn't seem to work. The items from the select element are saved in a variable. But when I echo this variable I don't get "Array" printed out. Here's the full code I used if that will help http://pastie.org/685106 (excuse the lack of code intends and please ignore the table based code ;) )

Answer (score 4):

If you give the select a name followed by [] in the form,

```
 name="my_select[]"
```

you will get an array in the target PHP script that you can parse.

Answer (score 0):

```
<select name="mySelection[]" multiple="multiple"> 
  <option></option> 
  <option></option>
  <option></option>
</select>
```

This will let you to access the multiple choice you in php